# Debugging protractor using inspector

Tags: node.js, protractor, angular-cli, inspect

I am trying to debug protractor e2e tests, using inspector as per protractors docs, the command I am executing is as follows:

`> node --inspect-brk node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng e2e --port 6666`

Debugger is listening on port 9229 and after hitting inspect in chrome://inspect/#devices on the target the compilation starts but I am getting an error `Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use`. It seems that cli tries to launch the inspector on the same port again. Why is that happening, is there any workaround to get that working?